# Access to readonly Rally account in app displayed outside of rally

Tags: javascript, sdk, rally

I'm using Rally SDK 1.33 to display Rally apps outside of Rally. I've generated a Rally login key on Rally's Login Key Encoder site and have used that value like so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.26/sdk.js?loginKey=..." />
```

The problem is, some members on my scrum team have been getting the following error message when trying to display my .html page:

```
    "unable to login user: ... on https://rally1.rallydev.com/ "
```

I'm looking for a way to let all members of my team have access to the readonly Rally account so they can view this html page. Anyone know of a way to do this without using the Login Key Encoder or is there something else I/my team members need to do in order to get access to the readonly account using this Login Key value? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unusual that for some users the read-only credentials work, and for others do not. When a custom app is loaded in a browser with read-only credentials encoded:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.25/sdk.js?loginKey=YOUR LOGIN KEY GOES HERE"></script>
```

the only user that matters is the one whose credentials are encoded and used in this string.

Perhaps there are 3rd party authentication issues. You mention that you are trying to display an app outside of Rally, but is this app being loaded directly in the browser or, for example, as a Sharepoint webpart, or in some other portal. If it's the latter, you may want to start troubleshooting directly in the browser. After it's established that it works in a browser, the app can be loaded in a context of a 3rd party portal.

If in some scenarios LoginKey seems to work and in others it does not I'd guess that it actually never works. It may appear to work when a valid user is logged in to Rally in another tab of the same browser, and it is using that user's credentials and not the read-only user's credentials. Please verify where the request is going in the Net tab of Chrome's Dev Tools or Firebug of Firefox:

[image]

It should show loginapirally1.rallydev.com, and not rally1.rallydev.com

Finally, a couple of points on the read-only user:

1. a read-only user that you create must have no editor rights to any project within the Rally workspace where you want to use the LoginKey functionality. If you have a deeply nested project structure please make sure there are no projects where this user has editor rights.
2. a user that used to be a workspace admin and later demoted to a read-only user will not work with LoginKey. A user like that would not be recognized by LoginKey as a read-only user.
3. prior to accessing the encoded page to generate the encoded string for a read-only user please log out of Rally if you are currently logged in to Rally in another tab of the same browser with a editor or administrator credentials. There is certainly a redundancy there: you will need to login to Rally with those read-only credentials, and then access the encoder page and will be asked for the same credentials again.